# Unable to set value in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a dropdownlist,while editing i need to set the current value.But my codes are not working.

My view look like follow

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, Model.ddls, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Model

```
  public string id { get; set; }
  public List<SelectListItem> ddls { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult editmaster(string id, string sec)
    {
      master m = new master();//here is my model
      m.ddls = PopulateDDLDataSet(ds.Tables[1], "companyname", "companyid");//ddls is my object and populateddldataset is my methode to fill the list
      return View(m); 
    }
```

ddls is the selectedlistitems that i have filled from controller,that work fine.But the value which in in id not set on the list

Comment: show the controller action code and Model as well

Comment: Iam updated my codes.Please have a look

Comment: Can you look at the View Source of the page and make sure that m.id match a value inside an <option> exactly.

Comment: You do not return m.Id together as m.ddls

Answer (score 0):

Checked the code and its working for me. Could you provide more details about your model? 
Wanted to say that you can make similar things by using built-in razor tag helpers that is more clear.

[Documentation for select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-select-tag-helper)

Example of using tag helper in your code:

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.id" asp-items="Model.ddls">
<option selected>Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow this, it may be this code help you.

**Model Code**

```
public class testmdl
{
      public string id { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ddls { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
//------ without using entity for select list items
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
                  testmdl obj=new testmdl();
                   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> companyList = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "001", Text = "StackOverflow1" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "002", Text = "StackOverflow2" }
                    };
                  obj.ddls =companyList ;
                  return View(obj);
    }
//--- using entity framework for select list items
    public IActionResult Test()
        {
                      testmdl obj=new testmdl();
                       List<SelectListItem> companyList = new SelectList(db.yourcompanytable, "companyid", "comapnyname").ToList();
                      obj.ddls =companyList ;
                      return View(obj);
        }
```

**View Code**

```
<select id="id1" name="id1" asp-for="id" asp-items="@Model.ddls" class="form-control">
      <option value=@null>--- Select --- </option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="id" style="color:red;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above answers work(I  don't clearly understand what went wrong for me)  ,but finally i achieved in an alternative way.Below my codes.Thanks for all the supports.

```
        <script>
            document.getElementById("id").value =@Model.id;
        </script>
```

Put this after binding the dropdownlist.